# Open command prompt from Visual Studio instead of Powershell for python execution

Tags: python, visual-studio, powershell

I'm using Visual studio (not "code") to debug python projects, my problem is that a project contains a sh script wrote for linux that needs to be run.
Visual studio offers only the "run in powershell" command, however powershell doesn't work with cygwin, and command prompt does.
I tried to run the command prompt from myself but I can't activate the python virtual environment that visual studio is using, I have a permission denied.

```
H:\git\someproject>H:\git\someproject\MYVENV\Scripts\python.exe -m venv MYVENV
Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'H:\\git\\someproject\\MYVENV\\Scripts\\python.exe'
```

Then, isn't there an option to use command prompt instead of powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this out as well: if you look at the top right corner of the terminal:
[image]

click on the dropdown beside the `+` sign and click `Command Prompt`. If you want to close the powershell hover over its tab and click the trash button.

Comment: I wasn't using the terminal view, Thank you !